# Keycloak login-status-iframe.html page is in Quirks Mode causing home page stuck?

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have implemented SSO in Angular application via Keycloak using Keycloak-js. Wenn Keycloak server was running on my localhost, everything was fine. Later when we tried a remote Keycloak server then until Dec 2021 it was working on Firefox but last week in Jan 2022 I got the Firefox update and now both Firefox and Chrome rejected the cookies because of the insecure server. Then we switched the server to https and used a self signed certificate.
Now the application is redirected to Keycloak and after logging in, user is redirected to the home page but the buttons and language resource bundle are not visible. When I refresh the page user is again redirected to Keycloak's login page.
I am using Angular v12, Keycloak-angular v9.1.0, keycloak-js v16.1.0, Node v16 and Keycloak v16.1.0.
In Firefox console, I see some warnings e.g:
**This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “”. login-status-iframe.html**

**Object { message: "..frontend\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs3\core-js\array\from.js depends on 'core-js-pure/features/array/from'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts." } index.js**
In Chrome however, user is not redirected to the Keycloak at all.

Here is my environment.ts code:

```
let keycloakConf: KeycloakConfig = {
  url: 'https:XXX/keycloak/auth/',
  realm: 'my-realm',
  clientId: 'my-client',
};

let keycloakInitOptions: KeycloakInitOptions = {
  messageReceiveTimeout: 10000, // Milliseconds
  checkLoginIframe: true,
  checkLoginIframeInterval: 60, // Seconds
  enableLogging: true,
  redirectUri:
    window.location.origin + '/my_domain/' + AppUrl.HOME,
};

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backendUrl: '/backend/xyz/',
  keycloakConf: keycloakConf,
  keycloakInitOptions: keycloakInitOptions,
};
```

Here is app.module.ts

```
function initKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: environment.keycloakConf,
      initOptions: environment.keycloakInitOptions,
    });
}
..
..
providers: [
    ConfirmationService,
    MessageService,
    { provide: ENV_TOKEN, useValue: environment },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initKeycloak,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally the Authentication-guard.ts

```
export class AuthenticationGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {

  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloakService: KeycloakService,
  ) {
    super(router, keycloakService);
  }

  async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {

    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloakService.login(environment.keycloakInitOptions);
    }

    return this.authenticated;
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

### EDIT

I figured out that my AuthenticationGuard is not returning true for canActivate() method (I also overrided it) and isAccessAllowed() is not even called. If I just return true the all the buttons on Home are visible but if I press F5 to refresh I am logged out and redirected to Keycloak.

Comment: Don't use iframes. Use PKCE flow and standard refresh tokens.

Comment: can you please explain your suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Iframe needs a third party cookie access, which will be (or is) blocked by all majority browsers, e.g. Safari has started in 2020 https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/ - that old school "silent token refresh via iframe" is really problem these days due to this security measures in the browsers.

Comment: All good OIDC libs (yes, Keycloak is OIDC compliant, so you really don't need any "keycloak" in the lib name) offers you PKCE flow, which doesn't need a iframe. Instead of that uses refresh tokens, which will be working perfectly with all modern browsers. Keycloak-js has PKCE as well (key settings: `checkLoginIframe: false`, `pkceMethod: 'S256'`). Implement PKCE properly and you will not have any problem  with any modern browser for now.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this Issue by adjusting the URL for Keycloak. There was an additional port number in there when removed it worked as expected.